# Best SE site for image processing questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which SE site is on topic for image processing questions?

Since I have seen some questions posted on [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) and also on Stack Overflow are closed as off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends ... many sites have questions about image processing, and you need to check each site's help center ([example](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) to determine which is the best fit (if any).

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags?query=image-processing) shows that there are no less than 13 sites with more than 100 image processing questions. Without seeing the actual question, it's hard to tell which one is best.

[image]

Comment: Codegolf is probably very special, but for the other sites there is considerable overlap especially on this tag. For a question on this tag that would be ontopic on multiple exchanges it would come down to where most of the specific experts reside. One would need to check similar questions and how well they are answered. Thanks for the query, one can learn so much from your SEDE queries.